# FacebookからRSS出力を取得する方法

Tags: facebook

こんにちは。
今まで、FacebookからRSSが出力されていてそれを利用していたのですが、RSSが出力されなくなったのに本日気づきました。
何か仕様が変わったのでしょうか？

http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=(ID番号)&format=rss20

として使っていました。

Answer (score 1):

仕様が変わってRSSはそのままでは取得できなくなったようです。
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog?locale=en_US#v2_3_90_day_deprecations

Comment: ありがとうございます。とても助かりました。